# MVC - Show Partial View on SelectBox Index Change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a selectbox with various key-value pairs.  What I want to do, is when I select an item in the selectbox, I want to use that selected key-value pair to show a form (partial view) and populate it with values based on that selected value.  I figure I need a callback to my controller or something that returns the partial view, but don't know how to exactly do that since its beyond the typical MVC workflow I've been using. Any links to help me research how to do this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See accepted SO answer here [Dynamically loading partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587485/dynamically-loading-partial-view).

If javascript is disabled in the browser you would need a trigger, e.g a button, to fire the postback to all the action.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a view which renders a HTML Select like this

```
<select id="states">
  <option value="1">MI</option>
  <option value="2">NY</option>
  <option value="3">CA</option>
</select>
<div id="partialContent"> </div>
```

We will capture the change event of this SELECT element and make an ajax call to a server to get the partial view content

```
<Script type="Text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $("#states").change(function(){
     var stateId=$(this).val();
     $("#partialContent").load("@Url.Action("StateDetails","State")/"+stateId);
   });
 });

</script>
```

This will make an ajax GET call to get the response from `StateDetails` action method in `State` controller by passing the parameter id with value as selected value of the HTML Select.

```
public ActionResult StateDetails(int id)
{
  var stateDetail=myRepositary.GetStateDetail(id);
  return View(stateDetail);
}
```