# Pass a string to view for use as parameter in Html.Partial

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I have a Controller and a Model:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ribbon = new RibbonModel();
        ribbon.Link = "_RibbonIndex";
        return View(ribbon);
    }

}
public class RibbonModel
{
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use it in a view to call a partial view:

```
@model MyNamespace.Controllers.RibbonModel

@Html.Partial(model => model.Link)
```

I get an error (bad translated):

> 'lambda-expression' cannot converted to 'string'...

I tried it also with ViewBag and ViewData, nothing works. Any idea? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, you have wrongly calling result of a model property assignment in lambda as partial view name. You should tell which partial view name to use, e.g. `@Html.Partial("PartialViewName", Model)` and assign the `Link` property inside partial view file.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto What I try is to load the partial view dynamically, the model is only for that reason, I don't need it actually. I want just to say the view which partial view it should load.

Comment: Try understanding concept on these similar issues first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313444/dynamically-load-partial-views & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587485/dynamically-loading-partial-view. If the partial view requires some data processing (e.g. retrieve from DB), `@Html.RenderAction` is more suitable over `@Html.Partial`.